# Mobile Broadband Sierra Gobi 3000 drivers compile under kernel 3.2

Tags: linux, mobile, broadband

I got drivers from here: [Codeaurora](https://www.codeaurora.org/contribute/projects/gobi/).

I was able to build drivers easily under 2.6.32 Kernel but due to other problems i had u had to upgrade kernel to 3.2 from back ports squeeze.

Now i got everything working. just i can't build those drivers any more.

I found tip from somebody to add in `.c` file:

`#include <linux/module.h>`

But it didn't work for me. (I read that here: https://www.codeaurora.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=15&t=141)

This is what i get after make:

```
rm -rf *.o *~ core .depend .*.cmd *.ko *.mod.c .tmp_versions Module.* modules.order
make -C /lib/modules/3.2.0-0.bpo.3-amd64/build SUBDIRS=/home/user/Desktop/gobi/GobiSerial modules
make[1]: Entering directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-0.bpo.3-amd64'
  CC [M]  /home/user/Desktop/gobi/GobiSerial/GobiSerial.o
/home/user/Desktop/gobi/GobiSerial/GobiSerial.c: In function ‘GobiOpen’:
/home/user/Desktop/gobi/GobiSerial/GobiSerial.c:409: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘long unsigned int’
/home/user/Desktop/gobi/GobiSerial/GobiSerial.c: In function ‘GobiClose’:
/home/user/Desktop/gobi/GobiSerial/GobiSerial.c:485: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘long unsigned int’
  Building modules, stage 2.
  MODPOST 1 modules
  CC      /home/user/Desktop/gobi/GobiSerial/GobiSerial.mod.o
  LD [M]  /home/user/Desktop/gobi/GobiSerial/GobiSerial.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-0.bpo.3-amd64'
```

If you have any clue pls.

Comment: So, lines 485 and 409 need to have %ld instead of %d - whether what will fix anything else that may be wrong, I'm not sure.

Comment: unfortunately it is not that straight forward :(

Comment: Meaning, if you fixe those problems, something else breaks? If so, explain what!

Comment: Same error just saying %ld instead %d

Comment: Gah, yes, it should be %lu, since it's UNSIGNED.

Comment: I understand you but it's so strange that compiling under different os/kernel i would also get same error and infect i didn't have any errors there... :(

Comment: I think the main reason is that 2.6 kernel was not so strict with warnings. From 3.x, there are a lot more strict handling of errors/warnings. And I would also guess that you have moved from 32 to 64-bit, perhaps?

Comment: I don't know much about what is new in 3.x kernels.. maybe you are right. Both OS were amd64.

Comment: So, I haven't downloaded the source for this, so I can't say for sure what has changed - maybe nothing, maybe it was always broken on 64-bit, but the older kernel wasn't strict on warnings, so it built fine. 

I have been building 3.7 from rc4 to 3.8 for work reasons, and I have noticed that things that used to compile in a 2.x kernel (with warnings, that I'd fix - warnings aren't OK in my book) are now failing to compile. Just a change of policy. So is the driver working with %lu?

Comment: No it fails to compile with %lu.
Thank you for comments i didn't know that things are getting more strict.

Comment: What is the exact error message? Please edit your original question.

Comment: As i said same error same line for error just prints out -> http://paste.debian.net/218923/

Comment: OU you were right i didn't pay attention. There were two arguments one war int another war unsigned... thank you it compiles.

Comment: So, do you mind if I write an "answer" from this?

Comment: go ahead i'm glad i find out solution...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
/home/user/Desktop/gobi/GobiSerial/GobiSerial.c: In function ‘GobiOpen’:
/home/user/Desktop/gobi/GobiSerial/GobiSerial.c:409: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘long unsigned int’
/home/user/Desktop/gobi/GobiSerial/GobiSerial.c: In function ‘GobiClose’:
/home/user/Desktop/gobi/GobiSerial/GobiSerial.c:485: warning: format ‘%d’ expects type ‘int’, but argument 4 has type ‘long unsigned int’
```

THis error is caused by printk not having the right format string. Use %lu in the right place in the format string.

This was PROBABLY broken in 2.6 as well, but may have passed through as a warning rather than an error, because of stricter settings for the compiler in the 3.x kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where the build failed at all given your compiler output:

```
  LD [M]  /home/user/Desktop/gobi/GobiSerial/GobiSerial.ko
make[1]: Leaving directory `/usr/src/linux-headers-3.2.0-0.bpo.3-amd64'
```

This looks like it succeeded to me. Check to see if you have the file `/home/user/Desktop/gobi/GobiSerial/GobiSerial.ko` and if so, then volia, it worked.

It's amazing that everyone else here has answered about some printk() format when it's obvious you didn't write this driver, and it's obvious the build succeeded.

Did you make sure to run `make install` after `make` and before `modprobe GobiSerial`?

Comment: I don't even remember what i fixed, but i know that it works now :D